# POSIX shell function for asking questions

Tags: validation, console, shell, sh, posix

I've written a tiny function for asking questions intended for my POSIX shell scripts, where I often need user input.

The function takes 2+ arguments, where:

1. Is a string containing the question.
2. , 3., ... = arguments containing the right answers (case insensitive)

I also changed my style by a bit, no longer use `${var}` instead of just `$var`.

The requirement was simple: Check for exactly the answers given. So, not matching `yeahh` if given answer is `yeah`.

I also included a maybe performance-wise quick test if the user answer is in the list of answers, so answering `no` will not make the script iterate through all the answers and just dies at that check.

---

```
#!/bin/sh
set -u
confirmation ()
# $1    = a string containing the question
# $2,.. = arguments containing the right answers (case insensitive)
{
    question=$1; shift
    correct_answers=$*
    correct_answers_combined=$( printf '%s' "$correct_answers" | sed 's/\( \)\{1,\}/\//g' )
    printf '%b' "$question\\nPlease answer [ $correct_answers_combined ] to confirm (Not <Enter>): "
    read -r user_answer

    # this part is optional in hope it would speed up the whole process
    printf '%s' "$correct_answers" | grep -i "$user_answer" > /dev/null 2>&1 ||
        return 1

    # this part iterates through the list of correct answers
    # and compares each as the whole word (actually as the whole line) with the user answer
    for single_correct_answer in $correct_answers; do
        printf '%s' "$single_correct_answer" | grep -i -x "$user_answer" > /dev/null 2>&1 &&
            return 0
    done

    # this might be omitted, needs verification, or testing
    return 1
}

# EXAMPLE usage, can be anything, DO NOT review this part please
if confirmation 'Is dog your favorite pet?' y yes yep yeah
then
    tput bold; tput setaf 2; echo 'TRUE: You just love dogs! :)'; tput sgr0
else
    tput bold; tput setaf 1; echo 'FALSE: Dog hater, discontinuing! :('; tput sgr0
    exit 1
fi
# do other stuff here in TRUE case
echo 'And here comes more fun...'
```

Comment: What if I answer `.*`? That's not in the list of accepted answers, yet it is accepted.

Comment: What if one of the valid answers contains a space?

Comment: @RolandIllig it can't contain space, I didn't think of `.*`, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf '%b'` will expand backslash escapes in `$question` and in `$correct_answers_combined`.  It's not obvious that both of those are desirable.

I'd probably re-write that to expand only `$question`, and to avoid an unnecessary pipeline:

```
printf '%b\nPlease answer [ ' "$question"
printf '%s ' "$@"
printf '] to confirm (Not <Enter>): '
```

You almost certainly want `fgrep` (or `grep -F`) rather than standard regular-expression `grep`, and it would be simpler to search through the items one per line, rather than using a `for` loop:

```
read -r user_answer

printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep -qFx "$user_answer"
```

If this is the last command in the function, then the return status will be that of the `grep` command, which is just what we need.

Finally, be aware that `read` can fail (e.g. when it reaches EOF).  If you don't want that to be an automatic "no", then make provision for that.  I don't know what the right behaviour is for this application so I'll leave that as an open issue for you to address appropriately.

---

## Modified version

Here's what I ended up with:

```
# $1    = a string containing the question
# $2,.. = arguments containing the right answers (case insensitive)
confirmation()
{
    question=$1; shift

    printf '%b\nPlease answer [ ' "$question"
    printf '%s ' "$@"
    printf '] to confirm (Not <Enter>): '
    read -r user_answer

    printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep -qFxi "$user_answer"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts. There really isn't any need for `correct_answers_combined`. After `shift`, `$*` will hold the combined remaining arguments (answers) to your question. The additional `printf`, pipe, and call to `sed` are simply incurring additional overhead in the form of subshells and separate utility calls. You could do:

```
    correct_answers="$*"

    ## prompt
    printf '%b' "$question\\nPlease answer [ $correct_answers ] to confirm (Not <Enter>): "
    read -r user_answer
```

Since you do not want to accept <kbd>[Enter]</kbd> as an answer, a validation that `user_answer` is unset can provide the answer and return for your function in that case, e.g.

```
    ## validate answer provided
    [ -z "$user_answer" ] && return 1
```

Your `"optional... speed up the whole process"`, with a bit of rearranging can be used as a single call to provide a return to your function. Since you want to know whether the `user_answer` exists among the `correct_answers` you can simply return the result of `grep -qi`:

```
    # this part is can be the whole process
    printf '%s\n' $correct_answers | grep -qi "$user_answer" > /dev/null 2>&1
        return $?
}
```

(**note:** using `printf '%s\n' "$correct_answers"` will separate each of the whitespace separated answers by `newline` which eliminates any possible combination of parts of adjacent answers returning true)

With those suggestions, your `confirmation ()` function would reduce to:

```
confirmation ()
# $1    = a string containing the question
# $2,.. = arguments containing the right answers (case insensitive)
{
    question="$1"; shift
    correct_answers="$*"

    ## prompt
    printf '%b' "$question\\nPlease answer [ $correct_answers ] to confirm (Not <Enter>): "
    read -r user_answer

    ## validate answer provided
    [ -z "$user_answer" ] && return 1

    # this part is can be the whole process
    printf '%s\n' "$correct_answers" | grep -qi "$user_answer" > /dev/null 2>&1
        return $?
}
```

I haven't tested all corner cases, but for single word answers it should function as you intend. If you want the some delimiter between the answers inside `[ ... ]` then an additional command substitution can be used, but space separated options appear fine between the brackets.

Let me know if you have any questions over the changes.

**Edit In Response to You Comments**

As stated above, if you want delimiters between the possible correct answers, simply use a *command substitution*, e.g.

```
## prompt
printf '%b' "$question\\nPlease answer [ $(echo $correct_answers | tr ' ' /) ] to confirm (Not <Enter>): "
read -r user_answer
```

If you are concerned about the expansion of `printf '%s\n'`, don't quote the `$correct answers`,

```
# this part is can be the whole process
printf '%s\n' $correct_answers | grep -qi "$user_answer" > /dev/null 2>&1
    return $?
```

Otherwise based on your stated question, it performs identical to the original saving at least half-a-dozen unnecessary subshells.